# Probability more than 25% greater?

Tags: normal-distribution

The random variable X is distributed N(60,64).
The random variable Y is distributed N(52,36).

Find the probability that a random observation from X is **more than 25% greater** than a random observation of Y.

Comment: Any thoughts yourself?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe it's P(X>5/4Y).. but I didn't get the answer :(

Comment: Hint: 1) $\Pr(X > 5/4 Y) = \Pr(X - 5/4 Y > 0)$. 2) sum of independent normal distributed variables is normal again.

Answer (score 2):

Outline: We do indeed want $\Pr(X\gt 5Y/4)$ or equivalently $\Pr(W\gt 0)$ where
$$W=X-\frac{5}{4}Y.$$
If we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are **independent**, then $W$ is normally distributed, with mean $E(X)-\frac{5}{4}E(Y)$ and with variance $\text{Var}(X)+\frac{25}{16}\text{Var}(Y)$.

Compute the mean and variance of $W$. The rest should be standard.

Comment: that's much more clever than the way I was suggesting doing it.  Well spotted.

Comment: @user261967: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you half way there.

Suppose we have obtained an observation from Y.  Call it $y$.  I want to express these probability densities as functions.  So let g(x) be the probability density of X and h(y) be the probability density of Y.  You can formally write the probability that an observation from X is at least 25% greater than it as

$P(x > 1.25y) = \int_{1.25y}^\infty $ g(x) dx

Now you just have "sum" this over all possible values of $y$, properly weighted by the probability density of $y$.